# Sequences and series general formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

In a question I have been solving, I needed to find a formula for the sum of this sequence

$$n$$

$$n-1, n-1$$

$$n-2, n-2, n-2$$
$$etc$$

$$1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...1$$

so the sum would be

$$(n+ 2(n-1) + 3(n-2) +... + 2(n-1) + n) $$
but how would you find a general formula for this, since I need to find n for a specific sum that was given

Comment: since there are n 1's and n-1 2's at the end, it is sort of like a pyramid

Comment: Yeah but there are n 1's at the last row, so the sum would be n*1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(n-k+1)=n\sum_{k=1}^{n}k-\sum_{k=1}^nk^2+\sum_{k=1}^nk.$$

Now, use

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} \quad \text{ and } \sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, sum diagonally:

$\hspace{1cm}$[image]

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i j=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1+i}{2}\cdot i=\sum_{i=1}^n {i+1\choose 2}={n+2\choose 3}=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}.$$
Reference: [Tetrahedral numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number).